# Reading HTML Table Head value in Adobe DTM

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-analytics

I'm using Adobe DTM and I'm trying to get the value from a table (I have no control over this format or naming) and I'd like to grab the value of "Opened Account" in the example below but not sure how to go about it in DTM? I'm trying to target "th.rich-table-headercell" but not sure how to grab value?

`<table class="rich-table home table" id="startForm:OpenedReviewApps" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <colgroup span="0"></colgroup>
    <thead class="rich-table-thead">
       <tr class="rich-table-header">
           <th class="rich-table-headercell" scope="colgroup">Opened Accounts</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody id="startForm:OpenedReviewApps:tb">
         <tr class="rich-table-row rich-table-firstrow">
             <td class="rich-table-cell" id="startForm:Open" style="width:80%">
                some data here
             </td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this, depending on what/when/where you are trying to get the value (e.g. page load rule vs. event based rule), but in general, based on your html, here is one way to do it.

Go to **Rules** > **Data Elements**, and click on **Create New Data Element**.

**Name** the Data Element something like "table_header" or whatever convention you currently use.

For **Type**, choose "CSS Selector".

For **CSS Selector Chain**, use "th.rich-table-headercell" (no quotes).

For **get the value of**, select "text".

(Optional, but recommended) Check the **Scrub whitespace and linebreaks using cleanText** option.

[image]

Now, for example, you can create a page load rule, and use `%table_header%` in your condition(s) or variable field(s). Or, if you need to reference it in javascript in a custom code box, use `_satellite.getVar('table_header')`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can use th[class="rich-table-headercell"]. Like if I have input field with name "username", will the CSS Selector chain be input.name? or input[name="username"]? thanks a lot.

Comment: @HussamEddin For the class, it's not a direct equivalent. The example I showed will select if the element has that class (but the element can have other classes, too). You can use that alternate syntax for the class if it's the _only_ class the element has.  But you cannot do `input.name` because that dot syntax is for class values specifically, not attributes in general.  This isn't actually a DTM specific question; it's CSS (Selector) syntax question (e.g. what you'd pass to `document.querySelector()` ). So if you want more info about that, look into CSS syntax, not DTM